# No se ejecuta el ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, devexpress

Ayuda, necesito pasar ese parámetro a ese método en, pero el javascript no entra a la parte del type y la url

```
function buscarId() {
    var cliente = GridViewBuscarCliente.GetRowKey(GridViewBuscarCliente.GetFocusedRowIndex());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Consumidores/GridViewPartialConsumidores",
        data: { "id": cliente },
        success: function (cliente) {
            $("#modalConsumidor").modal("hide");
        },
        fail: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    console.log(cliente);
}

public ActionResult GridViewPartialConsumidores(int ? id)
        {
            var model = db.TablaConsumidores.Where(s => s.Id_Cliente == id);
            return PartialView("_GridViewPartialConsumidores", model.ToList());
        }
```

este es el método al que necesito entrar

Comment: Saludos. No se aprecia como tienes `GridViewPartialConsumidores` declarado; por que dependiendo que uses `WebMethod` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services) puede ser lo que te falte, se necesita saber donde está ese método; por la forma como lo pones me parece es un Controller. Pero hay que esperar lo completes (al menos de momento es mi opinión).